# Fourier transform of 3D Sinc function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, special-functions

What is the Fourier trasnform of the function

$$\frac{\sin(P|\mathbf{x-y}|)}{|\mathbf{x-y}|}$$

where $P$ is a real parameter and $\mathbf{y}$ is a fixed point in three-dimensional space?

Answer (score 5):

It is a function with support on a sphere of radius $P$:
$$
\frac {e^{i(\xi,y)}}{4\pi P}\delta_{S_P}(\xi).
$$
It is closely related to the formula for the fundamental solution of the wave equation in $\mathbb R^3$. Namely, if to do a Fourier transform on the space variables of the equation 
$$
u_{PP}-\Delta u=\delta(x,P),
$$
then solving the resulting ODE one gets  almost the function in question, $\theta(P)\frac{\sin(P|\mathbf{\xi}|)}{|\mathbf{\xi}|}$. Here $\theta$ is the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

Answer (score 0):

I found it is

$i\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{y}}}{|\mathbf{k}|} \delta(P-|\mathbf{k}|)$